# Rest Assured java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am working on Rest assured framework to automate API testing. actually  I want to get the response as list not as an object. cause I want to do assertions for each element. to check data integrity for each element. I am executing this code:

```
    List<Category> categories = given().
            headers(
                    "Authorization",
                    "Bearer key",
                    "Content-Type",
                    ContentType.JSON,
                    "Accept",
                    ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .get("/rest/V1/categories").then().extract().response().jsonPath().getList("", Category.class);
```

This is the Category Class:

```
public class Category  {

private Long id = null;

private Long parent_id = null;

private String name = null;

private boolean is_active = true;

private int position = 0;

private int level = 0;

private int product_count = 0;

private ArrayList<Category> children_data = null;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getParent_id() {
    return parent_id;
}
public void setParent_id(Long parent_id) {
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
}

/**
 **/
public Boolean getIs_active() {
    return is_active;
}
public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
    this.is_active = is_active;
}

/**
 **/
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 **/
public int getProduct_count() {
    return product_count;
}
public void setProduct_count(int product_count) {
    this.product_count = product_count;
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}
public void setLevel(int level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}
public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}

/**
 **/
public List<Category> getChildren_data() {
    return children_data;
}
public void setChildren_data(List<Category> children_data) {
    this.children_data = children_data;
}
```

This is the console log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.util.HashMap and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

My Json raw:

{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "Default Category",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "product_count": 2046,
    "children_data": [
        {
            "id": 38,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "What's New",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 0,
            "children_data": []
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Women",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 2,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 1012,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "parent_id": 20,
                    "name": "Tops",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 784,
                    "children_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 23,
                            "parent_id": 21,
                            "name": "Jackets",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 1,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 186,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 24,
                            "parent_id": 21,
                            "name": "Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 182,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 25,
                            "parent_id": 21,
                            "name": "Tees",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 3,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 192,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 26,
                            "parent_id": 21,
                            "name": "Bras & Tanks",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 4,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 224,
                            "children_data": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "parent_id": 20,
                    "name": "Bottoms",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 2,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 228,
                    "children_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 27,
                            "parent_id": 22,
                            "name": "Pants",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 1,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 91,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 28,
                            "parent_id": 22,
                            "name": "Shorts",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 137,
                            "children_data": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Men",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 3,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 982,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "parent_id": 11,
                    "name": "Tops",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 678,
                    "children_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 14,
                            "parent_id": 12,
                            "name": "Jackets",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 1,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 176,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 15,
                            "parent_id": 12,
                            "name": "Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 208,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 16,
                            "parent_id": 12,
                            "name": "Tees",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 3,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 192,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 17,
                            "parent_id": 12,
                            "name": "Tanks",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 4,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 102,
                            "children_data": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "parent_id": 11,
                    "name": "Bottoms",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 2,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 304,
                    "children_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 18,
                            "parent_id": 13,
                            "name": "Pants",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 1,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 156,
                            "children_data": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 19,
                            "parent_id": 13,
                            "name": "Shorts",
                            "is_active": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "level": 4,
                            "product_count": 148,
                            "children_data": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Gear",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 4,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 46,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "Bags",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 14,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "Fitness Equipment",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 2,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 23,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "parent_id": 3,
                    "name": "Watches",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 3,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 9,
                    "children_data": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Training",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 5,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 6,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "parent_id": 9,
                    "name": "Video Download",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 6,
                    "children_data": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Collections",
            "is_active": false,
            "position": 5,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 989,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "New Luma Yoga Collection",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 347,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "Erin Recommends",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 2,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 279,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 35,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "Performance Fabrics",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 3,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 310,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 36,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "Eco Friendly",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 4,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 247,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 39,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "Performance Sportswear New",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 5,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 0,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 40,
                    "parent_id": 7,
                    "name": "Eco Collection New",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 6,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 0,
                    "children_data": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Promotions",
            "is_active": false,
            "position": 6,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 654,
            "children_data": [
                {
                    "id": 30,
                    "parent_id": 29,
                    "name": "Women Sale",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 1,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 224,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "parent_id": 29,
                    "name": "Men Sale",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 2,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 39,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "parent_id": 29,
                    "name": "Pants",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 3,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 247,
                    "children_data": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 33,
                    "parent_id": 29,
                    "name": "Tees",
                    "is_active": true,
                    "position": 4,
                    "level": 3,
                    "product_count": 192,
                    "children_data": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "parent_id": 2,
            "name": "Sale",
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 6,
            "level": 2,
            "product_count": 0,
            "children_data": []
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can you get how does your raw JSON looks like and add it to the question?

Comment: @chef417 Json raw has been added, thanks

Comment: Your JSON seems invalid - I tried copying it to online JSON editors and it reports invalid, e.g. try here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=local.qaqola&right=local.qecuzu .. Just from glancing, you seem to have 6 opened square brackets `[` and 3 closed ones `]`, which tells me the problem is probably the invalid JSON

Comment: @chef417 json provided is in the correct format.

Comment: @user3669148 try private List<Category> children_data = null; and edit getters/setters accordingly

Comment: @user3669148 also, try sending various test data. e.g., "children_data":null and only one  set in "children_data"

Comment: @user3669148 - Try adding `private Category[] children_data;` in Category class. And change the getters and setters.  And also, try chaging getList() method to `.getList("$", Category.class);` You will get a List<Category> with a single item. and all other `children_data` will be in the (Category type) array in that item. If you want to skip the initial object (`"name": "Default Category"`) and get all other `children_data` to List<Category>, then change getList() method to `.getList("children_data", Category.class);`

Comment: You want to get a `List<>` using `getList()` method but your JSON doesn't start with List. Instead of `getList` use `get` and it will work.

Comment: @kaweesha I think you can write the answer to the question

Comment: @Sara same error

Comment: @kaweesha I got the same problem

Comment: @Fenio I got this error: "class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class [Ldataentities.Category;"

Comment: @user3669148 Yes, sorry. The method is `getObject()` not `get()`. Cheers!

Comment: @Fenio I got this error:  "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `dataentities.Category` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)"

Comment: @user3669148 Great! Let me write the answer cause we just solved the issue

Comment: @Fenio What about the current error

Comment: @user3669148 Will be in the answer

Comment: @user3669148 Check out my answer and comment there with problems not stated in the question

Comment: @Fenio do you mean something like this: .getObject("", List<Category>);

Comment: Let me update the answer

Comment: @user3669148 Check edited answer

Comment: @kaweesha actually I want to get the response as list not as an object. cause I want to do assertions for each element. to check data integrity for each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get a `List<>` using `getList()` method but your JSON doesn't start with List. Instead of `getList` use `getObject` and it will work. `getObject()` maps the JSON to POJO class of your choice.

While deserializing JSON, you might encounter below issue

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of dataentities.Category (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

All you need to do is add a dependency to tell Rest-Assured which deserializer you want to use. 
My personal choice is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:
To deserialize JSON into a POJO you use `getObject()` method like this:

```
Category category = jsonPath.getObject("", Category.class);
```

EDIT:
You should make your `Category` class fields `public` OR create setters and getters. Otherwise, there will be exceptions.

Comment: Hey Fenio, Been following this question and a +1 for the answer but how do we get the values of children_data ? `categories.getId()` works and returns 2 but how do we get ID 38 ?

Comment: @WilfredClement The simplest solution is `category.children_data.get(0).id`

Comment: @WilfredClement I suppose you would like to know a solution using a specific approach?

Comment: I'd be happy to see if there is one, I just used `categories.getChildren_data().get(0).getId()` for the time being

Comment: @Fenio I got this error: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `dataentities.Category` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"

Comment: @user3669148 You should make your Category class fields public OR create setters and getters. Otherwise, there will be exceptions.

Comment: @Fenio I have setters and getters

Comment: @user3669148 I don't see it them in the question. Update your question then.

Comment: @WilfredClement How about `System.out.println(JsonPath.from(json).getObject("children_data.find { it.id == 38 }", Category.class).id);`? :)

Comment: Isn't that the data type of `children_data` should be `Category[]`?

Comment: @kaweesha Lists are supported

Comment: @user3669148 Why didn't you put that information in the question? Which list do you want to transform with POJO? Where are the setters and getters of Category class?

Comment: @Fenio actually I want to get the response as the list not as the object. cause I want to do assertions for each element. to check data integrity for each element. but by your solution, I cannot make that

Comment: @user3669148 You have the desired list `children_data` variable. Or you can use `List<Category> categories = Arrays.asList(jsonpath.getObject("children_data", Category[].class));` Also, read about POJO deserialization with Jackson. You need to annotate getters and setters with `@JsonProperty`.

And yes, you can check all fields with my solution because `Category` class contains everything you have in the JSON provided.

Comment: @user3669148 Stackoverflow's comment section is not the best place to chat or discuss good practices unless related to the solution. If I answer your question, kindly mark it as the accepted answer. If you have any questions NOT related to this question - file a new one OR visit my profile and contact me on Skype

Answer (score 0):

In your category class;

change `private ArrayList<Category> children_data = null;`

to `private List<Category> children_data = null;`

And try to execute with;

`.getList("children_data", Category.class);`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library for converting your json response into POJO

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use this statement to get the expected array of categories.

```
Response response = given()
        .headers("Authorization","Bearer key",
                 "Content-Type",ContentType.JSON,
                 "Accept",ContentType.JSON)
        .get("/rest/V1/categories");

Category[] categories = new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody().asString(),Category[].class);
```

Now Assert on categories or you may need to have a list, then Do this,

```
List<Category> categoryList = Arrays.asList(categories);
```