# Serializing using Rest Assured response.jsonPath().getObject() returns null

Tags: java, jackson, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have an API returning JSON which looks like this

```
{"listings":[
 {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "officia porro iure quia iusto qui ipsa ut modi",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "culpa odio esse rerum omnis laboriosam voluptate repudiandae",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/d32776",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "natus nisi omnis corporis facere molestiae rerum in",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/f66b97"
  },
]}
```

I want to serialize that JSON to my `MyObject` class. I just need 2 variables, so I will just ignore the others.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class MyObject {

    private String title;
    private String url;

    // Getters and Setters here
}
```

My test runner looks like this

```
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void runTest() {

    // Usual Rest-Assured GET request here

    Response response = request
      .request(Method.GET);


    List < MyObject > objects = Arrays.asList(response.jsonPath().getObject("listings", MyObject[].class));

    String testOneTitle = response.jsonPath().get("listings[0].title");
    System.out.println("testOneTitle " + testOneTitle); // OK - Returns String of the title

    System.out.println("Size " + objects.size()); // OK -Returns the size of the List

    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
      System.out.println("Title " + objects.get(z).getTitle()); // NOK - This returns null 
    }
  }
}
```

```
Title null
Title null
Title null
```

I don't know why it returns null.

I suspect this method doesn't serialize the JSON properly?

```
List < MyObject > objects = Arrays.asList(response.jsonPath().getObject("listings", MyObject[].class));
```

Any idea why?

Learning from the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293707/rest-assured-java-util-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-class-java-util-list) , I am guessing Rest-Assured uses 3rd party library to serialize JSON ? Not sure, but I follow the suggestion on that link by adding dependency

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.3'
```

Comment: You might as well use `response.jsonPath().getList("listings", MyObject.class)`, but I'm not sure whether that will help.

Comment: Thanks :)  `List<MyObject> objects = response.jsonPath().getList("listings", MyObject.class);` still gives me `null` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really go through the question in detail as I understood the context, It seems like the issue is with the POJO. Here's something I tried in my local machine and I am able to get the expected

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Listing {

    @JsonProperty("listings")
    public List<Listing> listings = null;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String title;
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String url;
    
    // Getters and Setters here

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Listing> res = RestAssured.given().when().get("http://localhost:8080/stack").then().extract()
            .response().as(Listing.class).getListings();

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
        System.out.println("Title " + res.get(z).getTitle());
    }

}
```

Comment: Apparently, `@JsonProperty("title")` is mandatory. Without it, `Jackson` won't be able to map the JSON to the POJO. I thought we need to use it only when we want to customize the variable name (to be different than what declared in the JSON) as described in chapter 5 in https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/. But that is not the case. Thanks for the answer.